# Parse XML to tree in C

Tags: c, xml

What is the smartest way to parse a nested XML-file into an (n-ary) tree in C without use of any libraries? Currently I have tried reading the lines separately with fgets and reading the file line by line, but it does not work as the contexts of the nested elements cant be taking into account. How would you go about doing this?

```
<!-- Root node -->
<root>
  <node_id>0</node_id>
  <n>2</n>
  <library_choice>1</library_choice>

  <!-- Child node -->
  <child level="1">
    <node_player>1</node_player>
    <node_id>1</node_id>
    <n>2</n>
    <library_choice>1</library_choice>
    <kr>11000</kr>

      <!-- Childs child node -->
      <child level="2">
          <node_player>2</node_player>
          <node_id>1</node_id>
          <library_choice>5</library_choice>
          <kr>11000</kr>
          <utility>100</utility>
      </child>

      <!-- Childs child node -->
      <child level="2">
          <node_player>2</node_player>
          <node_id>1</node_id>
          <library_choice>8</library_choice>
          <kr>11000</kr>
          <utility>100</utility>
      </child>
  </child>

  <!-- Child node -->
  <child level="1">
    <node_player>1</node_player>
    <node_id>2</node_id>
    <n>2</n>
    <library_choice>2</library_choice>
    <kr>10000</kr>

      <!-- Childs child node -->
      <child>
          <node_id>3</node_id>
          <node_player>2</node_player>
          <probability>0.5</probability>
          <utility>100</utility>
      </child>

      <!-- Childs child node -->
      <child>
          <node_id>6</node_id>
          <node_player>2</node_player>
          <probability>0.5</probability>
          <utility>100</utility>
      </child>
  </child>
</root>
```

Comment: What is a "nested XML file"? What is the data structure you're trying to build?

Comment: The smartest way is to use an existing library. The next smartest way is to use a state machine to track your descent against the DTD.

Comment: *Personally*, I'd use `libxml`, but you said "without any libraries".  Basically, you're going to have to implement your own full-up XML parser.  I've done that exactly once, many years ago.  It took a couple of days and sort-of-kind-of worked.

Comment: It would be good to know the reason for "without any libraries" in order to suggest other ways; are you dealing with huge xml files, such that a dom representation is to expensive? performance reasons? limited hardware / memory? ...

Comment: Do you need to write a *general-purpose* XML parser, or simply one that accepts your particular application of XML?  Or do you actually know enough about what you must accept to draw a meaningful distinction?

Comment: @JohnBollinger  I simply need to write one that accepts a particular application of XML. I only need to parse files that look exacly like the one above - with the possibility of more children. However if unlimited children becomes an issue I am allowed to set a limit to solve the task.

Comment: A formal syntax and grammar for XML is integrated into [the W3C's XML recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/).  You could rely on that to build a parser with some combination of the usual tools; for example, `flex` and `bison`.  That's not 100% from scratch, but it's also not using a for-purpose library.  It could carry you a long way.

Comment: @JohnBollinger And I am allowed to restructure the XML however I see fit. So if it makes more sense to restructure the XML in a way that makes it easier to parse into a tree that is also a solution.

Comment: @JohnLag, if you don't want to use a parser generator such as `bison`, then I would suggest writing a [recursive-descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) for your particular XML application.  They are relatively easy to write, and it would provide a natural structure for your code that helps you track the context in which each element appears.

Comment: @JohnLag, ideally, though, you would at least use an underlying XML parser in the style of expat and SAX to handle the details of XML syntax.  That would make a pretty solid foundation for your application-specific recursive-descent parser, though it would involve a third-party library.

Answer (score 0):

> I only need to parse files that look exacly like the one above - with the possibility of more children.

Since your file structure is quite simple and just happens to be also in XML format, it's indeed not necessary to use a full XML parser. Your approach *of reading the lines separately with fgets and reading the file line by line* wasn't bad, since *the contexts of the nested elements* can well be taken into account, e. g.:

```
char *tags[] =
{ "node_player","node_id","n","library_choice","kr","probability","utility",
  "child"
};
enum tags
{ node_player, node_id, n, library_choice, kr, probability, utility, child };
typedef struct node
{
    struct node *sibling,   /* next node on same level */
                *child;     /* next node on next level */
    float content[child];
} node_t;

#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *getln()
{
    static char ln[99]; // max. line length without '\n' is 97; adjust if needed
    char *s;
    do  if (!fgets(s = ln, sizeof ln, stdin)) puts("EOF"), exit(1);
        else while (isspace(*s)) ++s;   // skip leading space
    while (!s[0] || s[1] == '!');   // skip empty lines and comments
    if (s[0] != '<') printf("expected a tag, but got: %s\n", s), exit(1);
    return s;
}

node_t *parse(char *cp, char *tagname)
{
    int lng;
    if (strncmp(cp+1, tagname, lng = strlen(tagname)) != 0)
        printf("expected %s tag, but got: %s\n", tagname, cp), exit(1);
    node_t *np = malloc(sizeof *np);
    np->sibling = np->child = NULL;
    node_t **childp = &np->child;   // eventual child address stored here
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < child; ) np->content[i++] = HUGE_VALF;  // no value
    if (!np) puts("OOM"), exit(1);
    while (cp = getln(), cp[1] != '/' || strncmp(cp+2, tagname, lng) != 0)
    {
        char innnername[16];
        for (i = 0; strncmp(cp+1, tags[i], strlen(tags[i])) != 0; )
            if (++i > child) printf("unknown tag: %s\n", cp), exit(1);
        if (i == child) // a child element
            childp = &(*childp = parse(cp, "child"))->sibling;  // next child
        else            // a leaf element
            np->content[i] = atof(strchr(cp, '>')+1);   // ToDo: error check
    }
    return np;
}

int level;
void print(node_t *np)
{   // print a tree, show by example how to traverse it
    printf(level ? "%*cchild level %d:" : "root:", level, ' ', level);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < child; ++i) // first, print the existing leaf elements:
        if (np->content[i] != HUGE_VALF)
            printf(" %s=%g", tags[i], np->content[i]);
    puts("");
    ++level;
    for (np = np->child; np; np = np->sibling) print(np);
    --level;
}

main()
{
    node_t *root = parse(getln(), "root");
    level = 0, print(root);
}
```